# Cassandra db doesnt see new column families after backup restore

Tags: backup, cassandra, restore

I need to copy data from one KS to another KS. Keyspaces has different names.
I've made a snapshot of one keyspace and do all as said in datastax:
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/backup_restore
After start cassandra see old column families and doesn't see new column families in another KS.
What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you never CREATEd the columnfamilies in the new keyspace.